# Partition seems shrunk after cloning with Macrium Reflect

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, clone

I started getting SMART warnings on my 1TB WD disk, so to prevent losing the data, I went to buy a replacement. Since the disk was almost full, I decided to buy a 2TB one (a Seagate). I installed it, reformatted (verifying it was 2TB) and went to look how to clone the failing one.

I looked up on the net how to copy the data over in such a way as not to lose any system properties etc; one of pages suggested Macrium Reflect Free - I didn't need anything fancy, so I got it, the cloning went through, and as I went to check the result, there was the cloned partition, exactly the same size as original. I went to disk manager - and it's 2TB there. I ran the disk through chkdsk but it didn't help.

F: is the old, failing disk. E: is the new one.

[image]

What can I do to make it appear as 2TB in the OS, not just disk manager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to move my Windows installation to an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/252675/easiest-way-to-move-my-windows-installation-to-an-ssd)

Comment: @music2myear No, not even remotely. 1. Working post-factum repairing existing Macrium Reflect snafu, 2. not the system partition, 3. to a larger drive. While most of the solutions would work, they are massively overcomplicated for my situation - this is not the system drive, WinPE or other OS is completely unnecessary. As you can see the required solution was 4 lines in terminal. Using the others would be "shooting sparrows with a cannon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most filesystems have their own "size" independent of the underlying device (partition). It seems a bit like Reflect simply dumped the original filesystem into a larger partition, but did not update any NTFS structures to match.

From within Windows, you can probably fix this via DISKPART. Select the volume using `list vol` and `select vol num`, then grow the filesystem using `extend filesystem`.

Within Linux, you can use `ntfsresize` on the partition device.