# What will be a workflow of migrating OS and program from one SSD to another

Tags: clone

I have a 1TB SSD for C Drive (OS, programs). I now have a 4TB new SSD for D Drive. What I want to do is

1. Clone the content of C Drive to D Drive
2. Rename D Drive with OS as a new C Drive. Rename the old C drive as D Drive
3. Use the new D Drive for data

What will be a workflow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to move my Windows installation to an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/252675/easiest-way-to-move-my-windows-installation-to-an-ssd)

Comment: I try to do a disc clone not a system clone. (1) Use Macrium Reflect to clone c to d https://www.reddit.com/r/computers/comments/p8f1h9/best_free_disk_cloning_software (2) Then what will be the next step?

Comment: You're moving your OS to another drive. What you do surrounding that is immaterial and can be done, more or less, as you please. Though, knowing where your boot sector is will be important. Further, this is only one of the many questions on this site covering what your question lists. What research have you done and what have you tried?