# How to install Windows 8 without the setup DVD that came with my notebook?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free way to clone HDD to SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd)

Recently I bought an Asus u32vj and decided to change from its hdd to a smaller capacity ssd. The  problem is I can't figure out how to migrate Windows 8 to the ssd. Actually I don't need to migrate, I just want to install Windows 8 which came with my notebook without the DVD. I have the recovery installer residing on the recovery partition.

The recovery tool suggested in the manual "A recovery burner" is missing.

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use a clean Windows 8 DVD or MSDN/Technet ISO. This DVD detects the OEM Key which is now embedded to the BIOS:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithcombs/archive/2012/11/16/windows-8-bios-keys-embedded-goodness.aspx

> If you look at the bottom of my machine, you’ll notice there is no
>   Windows 8 Certificate of Authenticity (COA).  There is an official Windows 8 logo sticker, but no product key.
>
> The good news is that you no longer have to worry about it fading or
>   getting scratched.  The 5x5 key is embedded in the BIOS.  Therefore
>   all I had to do in order to install a fresh clean copy of Windows 8
>   was attach an external DVD drive, boot from the retail DVD, and run
>   setup. As soon as I connected to the internet, the machine activated. 
>   It never asked me for a key.  No fuss!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think they're saying in the manual that you need to use CD/DVD burning software to burn the data from the recovery partition to a couple of DVDs. Once you have these DVDs in hand you may be able to do the re-install and target the SSD instead of the HDD.