# Windows 8 License Transfer on a Toshiba Laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

So a friend of mine recently purchased a Toshiba Satellite C855.   The computer comes with Windows 8 pre-installed on a 5400 RPM SATA disk.

I had my friend purchase a 240GB SSD that I was planning on swapping his spinning SATA drive with to improve performance, however when I started looking for the Windows 8 license (which has traditionally been printed on a sticker on the bottom) I don't see anything at all.   I am going to need to transfer over the license since I am going to be switching out the hard disk and was wondering if anyone could tell me how I would go about obtaining the license so I can transfer it to the SSD install?   I still have his original HDD with Windows 8 installed on it if needed.

I originally tried to image his old HDD using HDClone Standard, but my computer does not seem to recognize the SATA HDD when I connect it to my primary desktop.   However if I reboot my primary desktop with the hdd plugged in, it attempts to boot Windows 8 so I know the hard drive works but for some strange reason I just cant get it to show up in the Disk Management MMC.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use a tool that tells you what the license is but transfer it to where exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 migrate from hdd to ssd](http://superuser.com/questions/523884/windows-8-migrate-from-hdd-to-ssd), [Replacing hard drive of laptop having geniune windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/556310/replacing-hard-drive-of-laptop-having-geniune-windows-8), []()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newly built machines that come preloaded with Windows 8, you won’t have a COA (Certificate of Authenticity) sticker attached to the machine anymore. Instead, this will be embedded in the BIOS. This will avoid product keys from being compromised and OEMs will buy what they need.

Windows installer should automatically read the key.