# Samsung SSD Migration Error, Windows Cannot Boot Correctly

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have recently purchased a Samsung 850 Pro SSD and I attempted to use their included software to transfer my OS (Windows 8.1) as well as my programs and files. I have included a link below related with my issue, please take a look at this scenario first, thanks. My process of installing and setting up the SSD is very similar to the method that this user performed. For a more detailed idea of my installation, I will also include all details of my exact experience:

1. Installed Samsung 850 Pro into open hard drive bay on my two bay gaming laptop. (Asus G750JX) I enable the drive as D:
2. Underwent the Samsung data migration procedure, transferring from my old HDD drive C: to D:
3. When completed, my drive D: has now been split into two partitions, D: with SYSTEM as title and F: as storage for applications and their data. Samsung's software indicates that I should install the SSD, (usually laptops are equipped with one drive) with the SSD technically already installed within the laptop, I "skipped" this step.
4. Samsung wanted me to reboot after "installing" the SSD, so I did. Referring from another internet article, I wanted to enter my laptop's BIOS/UEFI and change the boot order from my old HDD (C:) to my new SSD. (D: + F:)
5. I didn't hit esc quick enough, (which is the key used to access my laptop's BIOS/UEFI) therefore, I booted onto my C: drive one again. Checking my disks, I saw that my SSD was still in two partitions. This made me assume that I needed to set boot order for the migration to be successful.
6. Once again I reboot my laptop and this time, I successfully access the BIOS/UEFI. I change the boot order, save changes, and continue with the boot sequence. The Windows lockscreen appears, I check Windows Explorer and the SSD drive now has the Windows symbol and is now a single partition. (D:) I assume that the migration is successful. But further analysis shows that all applications are still booting from the old HDD C: drive.
7. I remove the hard drive, thinking that this will force the SSD to boot everything. I try booting once more, the Windows 8.1 lockscreen appears, my name and my email also appear. But my lockscreen wallpaper is now gone, my wireless connections are also not available and once I enter my password, the OS becomes constantly stuck on the Welcome and/or preparing Windows loading menu. (something like that)

Windows also cannot shut down using the software icon on the lockscreen.

Now here is where things get panicked, I foolishly decided to format my previous HDD drive! (C:) I understand that you should NEVER EVER FORMAT DATA WITHOUT A BACKUP... But I wanted to use the drive as a dedicated storage drive. So I now have no operable OS, and my data is inaccessible! (Data recovery is "possible", since I have not written anything to the old drive as of yet)

After reading the answer provided in the link below, I realized that Samsung's software is based on notebooks with only one drive bay. Therefore it required you to physically remove the previous drive and install the SSD. (which was externally connect to the PC via a SATA to USB cable) I should of kept the old hard drive as a backup, and I understand that I was very foolish when I decided to format the old HDD. But that's the situation.

I have also noticed a important factor, Samsung's software created two partitions on the SSD in preparation for the migration, SYSTEM and Data. These two combined when the SSD was booted to first.

Question(s):

I wish to know if there are any of you (Samsung technicians?) who can provide me with a solution to restore Samsung's migration setup, (two partitions, SYSTEM and Data, first boot will combine both partitions) or at least provide me a method of extracting at least the previous OS so I can make a clean install.

If no one is able to give me a solution for that issue, can some one give me clarification on the effectiveness of formatted data recovery? Can data recovery restore the drive to its former fully functional state? Or is it only possible to restore photos, videos, and documents? Is it at least possible to restore the OEM Windows 8.1 from the formatted hard drive? If so, how?

I know that this is a daunting task, and that this "question" may be too long for most people to comprehend, but if anyone has valuable advice, help or solutions, I would gladly appreciated it! Thank you for taking your time to help me out, I really hope that my issue can be solved in the best way possible. (If any of those who read this are Samsung employees with knowledge of this product and software, or knows someone who does, a helping hand would be appreciated)

If there were some details missing in my description, or if you would like for me to clarify a few things, please post a comment! I thank everyone in advance who would take their time to help me.

[Cannot boot Windows 8.1 after migrating to Samsung SSD using supplied software](https://superuser.com/questions/848692/cannot-boot-windows-8-1-after-migrating-to-samsung-ssd-using-supplied-software)