# best way to clone HDD to SSD Window 7

Tags: ssd, clone

This is really similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd) but some of the methods did not work for me. For example Clonezilla and GParted is not booting from my USB device (created with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)).

I was following [this guide](http://www.ssdfreaks.com/content/664/how-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd-with-windows-7s-own-software/3) but the the de-fragment process could not move the data to the disk so the shrink process ended shrinking 300GB (my ssd is 256GB and the data on the HDD is less than that).

1. Is there a BIOS option for booing Clonezilla or any other easy and clever way to clone my HDD?
2. In worse case scenario I am planning to clean install to SSD without touching HDD. Is there any way to clone my restore partition to USB drive as a bootable device?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a USB stick and copied Windows 7 installation files to it, and succeeded in installing Windows from it. I followed this guide:

**[Install Windows 7 Or Windows 8 From USB Drive](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/)**.

You could try this and skip the part where you copy the Windows files to the stick. Then you copy Clonezilla and try that.