# How to clone Windows HDD to a smaller SSD with Windows built in tool

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, ssd, imaging

I would like to move my OEM Windows from a big HDD to a smaller SSD. Windows 7 + SP1 has a built in toool.

My problem is that it could not find a way for it to make an image file only of the used blocks only of the Windows Drive on the HDD and not of the other logical drive on the same HDD.

Is there an MS based solution to this or I have to buy some backup tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free way to clone HDD to SSD?](http://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd)

Answer (score 0):

You can use most any disk cloning software. They run from a bootable DVD/CD so they are OS independent. One of the best is [clonezillia](http://clonezilla.org/). After cloning to the SSD, you might need to use a windows disk to rebuild the boot sector. Also read up on tweaks for Windows 7 running on SSD - like disabling auto-defrag.