# Upgrading machine to SSD, and upgrading OS

Tags: windows-8, ssd, upgrade

I am upgrading my machine(selfbuilt) to run on an SSD(250gb).

I want to put my OS and common apps on it, I know I am not exactly reinvinting the wheel here in terms of complicated questions, but I want to upgrade my OS at the same time(or before/after whatever is easiest) when installing the SSD. I am currently running win8 and would like to upgrade to 10.

I have looked for guides online but they are either unhelpful or too complicated.

Thank you.

EDIT:

The new SSD is a Samsung EVO 850 250gb.

I am assuming this comes with a software to help with this?

Comment: Some Samsung SSDs come with software to duplicate your current storage device to your SSD.  What has your research shown?  How you duplicate you current storage device to a SSD, is well documented.  There are literally hundreds of software choices to clone your HDD to your SSD.  **Just follow the guides you already found step by step.**

Comment: I am not very adept in computer hardware stuff, Most of what I have found is too confusing for me.

The cloning system looks like it would cause problems, cause I have over 250gb of data that would be put on a 250gb SSD, is there a way that I can only clone the OS?

Comment: If everything is on a single partition you will have to get rid of stuff or transfer it to another drive.  If you just want the OS, install a fresh installation of Windows 10, after you upgrade your current drive.  Windows 10 will automatically activate, this of course means, you have to install your applications again.

Comment: [some solutons](http://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd)

Comment: I am also adding 8tb worth of HDD drives (I do video editing, this is not overkill) to my system. I could transfer everything but the OS to there, then clone the OS, yes?

Then after I should be able to upgrade to win 10.

I think.

Comment: What you want to do isn't complicated.  Don't make it complicated.  Upgrade to Windows 10, disconnect old drive, connected ssd, install windows 10, connect old drive by usb [HDD docking station](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=hdd+docking+station).  You can also use the software package of your choice to clone your HDD to your SSD.  Just reduce the amount of storage to below 250 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I did this except it was from windows 7 to 10

All I did was move my SATA connections so that my new boot drive was going to the first port, and moved my previous boot drive to the subsequent ports, this probably doesn't matter since you can choose boot drive, but I did it anyway since I pretty much swapped out most of the parts

I then created a bootable Win 10 installation usb, installed the SSD and booted the USB from the boot menu, and then you can choose which drive to put the W10 install on, from that point on, you just follow the instructions until it's installed

I can still access my previous boot drives as storage