# New Computer with HDD, move to SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I am looking to purchase a new computer.  I reached out to Dell, and they were going to charge me about $1800 for a new desktop and when I started to inquire, found out that they were charging over $500 for a 2TB SSD, but I could find many for around $200.  At any rate, $1800 was out of my budget, so I started to research refurbished desktops with 2TB HDD.  However, I would still like to add a SSD drive to run my applications, but if the PC comes with Windows already installed on the HDD, how does one transfer the data so it runs off SSD for Windows and all applications, and just use the HDD as storage for files (photos, videos, music, etc).

Comment: You want to [clone your HDD to your SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd).

Comment: Many SSD makers provide a cloning tool to do exactly this, for example Samsung Magician, or WD give an HP branded Acronis, or you can download Macrium Reflect or some other cloning tool.