# How to clone an M.2 drive through a computer and USB-M.2 adapter?

Tags: ssd, clone, migration

want to upgrade the SSD size of my Laptop without reinstalling everything if possible.
The laptop has an M.2. drive and I have an M.2->USB adapter (like this https://www.amazon.de/-/en/FIDECO-Enclosure-10Gbps-Adapter-Supports/dp/B08CGJYJ7F ) which I have successfully tested with the target drive  already.
Unfortunately I have only one, so I cannot clone directly from drive to drive.

What software can I use to first copy the whole contents of the original SSD to a directory on my PC and then copy it back to the new SSD where it needs to be bootable.
Preferably a windows a solution would be great, but I could use a linux bootstick.

Huge thanks in advance :)

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd) mentions Windows 7 but the suggested solutions absolutely still apply to Windows 10 and a SSD. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1581803/what-is-the-most-efficient-native-way-to-image-a-windows-partition/1581804#1581804) might also be helpful.  At the end of the day there are any number of Windows third-party applications that can image your current SSD and restore that image on the new SSD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free way to clone HDD to SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd)

Comment: You have an internal M.2 slot and a USB M.2 adapter. That means you can connect two drives at the same time. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

Download the WinPE bootable iso here: https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/117664-win10xpe-build-your-own-rescue-media.html

Use Rufus to burn it and make a bootable flash drive

Boot it on the laptop and use Macrium ReflectPE to make an image of the drive to and external USB drive or something on your M.2 USB

Replace the SSD with a larger SSD and use the same process to drop the image back down on the bigger SSD.

It might let you make the image to the drive you are imaging. Not sure. You would be better off using and external USB drive.

*** Just tried it. It will not let you back up to the drive you are backing up but if you can shrink the main partition and create a new partition. Then you can can exclude that partition from the image backup and use it as the destination.